# Can a thread be context-switched while holding a lock?

Tags: multithreading

How do you take care of context-switching when a thread holds a lock and hence blocks other threads? I would expect it's a very common issue.

Comment: You need to clarify your question a little bit. Are you talking about a user application, holding one of its own locks? Making a system call holding a kernel lock? Kernel scheduling code holding locks? You don't give a lot of .. *context*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a pre-emptive multi-tasking system, you can't prevent yourself from being switched out while holding a lock.  But since anything else that's waiting on the lock (assuming that it's not a spinlock) can't be switched in, this is normally not a problem.

Using a spinlock is almost always a bad idea.  There are legitimate cases where things can go badly if you hold a lock too long; you can manage this by ensuring that you hold the lock for the least amount of time possible and that you don't do anything that can block while holding it.

Answer (score 0):

The blocked threads don't run, and eventually the thread holding the lock becomes active again, eventually releasing the lock.  You don't have to do anything special beyond the usual nitpicky care needed with multithreaded code.